# How To Create An Occurence Frequency Raster From a Stack Of Images Using Python

Tags: python, raster, band-ratio

I have a stack of single-band rasters calculated using the following band ratio on a stack of Sentinel 2 images.

Thermal Anomaly Index (TAI) = (B12 - B11) / B8A

This band ratio is helpful in identifying high-temperature anomalies in images. I am studying an industrial area, and I want to visualize the number of times the blast furnaces fire (TAI > 1).

Therefore, I want a raster that contains pixel values from 0 to X, where each pixel represents the number of times its value is greater than 1 in the stack of TAI images.

I used ChatGPT to get the following code, but the output doesn't seem right and pixel values range from 27 to 40, which cannot be possible as I physically checked that many pixels have no values greater than 1 throughout the whole stack.

```
import os
import rasterio
from rasterio.plot import show
import numpy as np

# Set the folder path
folder_path = r'C:\Users\DELL\OneDrive\Desktop\TAI\Gijon_TAI'

# Function to count occurrence frequency of TAI values > 1
def count_occurrence_frequency(file_paths):
    occurrence_frequency = None
    for file_path in file_paths:
        with rasterio.open(file_path) as src:
            # Read TAI raster as numpy array
            tai = src.read(1)
            
            # Mask values <= 5
            tai_masked = np.ma.masked_less_equal(tai, 1)
            
            # Convert masked array to binary array
            binary_array = tai_masked.mask.astype(int)
            
            # Sum binary array
            if occurrence_frequency is None:
                occurrence_frequency = binary_array
            else:
                occurrence_frequency += binary_array
                
    return occurrence_frequency

# Get list of raster files
raster_files = [os.path.join(folder_path, file) for file in os.listdir(folder_path) if file.endswith('.tif')]

# Count occurrence frequency
occurrence_frequency = count_occurrence_frequency(raster_files)

# Get metadata from one of the raster files
with rasterio.open(raster_files[0]) as src:
    meta = src.meta

# Update metadata for the new raster
meta.update(dtype=rasterio.uint16, count=1, nodata=0)

# Set the output file path
output_file = r'C:\Users\DELL\OneDrive\Desktop\TAI\occurrence_frequency.tif'

# Write the new raster file
with rasterio.open(output_file, 'w', **meta) as dst:
    dst.write(occurrence_frequency.astype(rasterio.uint16), 1)

print(f"Occurrence frequency raster saved to: {output_file}")
```